is there any method or webhook to get message response or message data from the telegram channel in c# without any use of bot?
i want to get message details and the message texts from the telegram channel. i have read and go through many solutions but didn't get result or answer i need. most of them are using bot but i want to get message details from the telegram channel directly using channel id or channel name. so is there any webhook or library for that?
i have channel id and channel name if there is any webhook or method in c#.
i have tried this code but it didn't work and not getting message from the channel.
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{

    string botToken = "XXXXXXX:AAAAAAAXXXXXXBBBBBCCCC";
    string channelUsernameOrId = "XXXXXXXXXXX";
    string apiUrl = $"https://api.telegram.org/bot{botToken}/setWebhook?url={channelUsernameOrId}";


    while (true)
    {
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            try
            {
                HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiUrl);
                response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                Console.WriteLine(responseBody); // Print the response

                // Parse the response JSON to get message details
                TelegramResponse telegramResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TelegramResponse>(responseBody);

                // Loop through messages and do something with them
                foreach (var message in telegramResponse.Result)
                {
                    // Access message text
                    string messageText = message.Message.Text;
                    Console.WriteLine($"Message from {message.Message.From.Username}: {messageText}");
                }
            }
            catch (HttpRequestException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Request error: {e.Message}");
            }
        }

        // Sleep for a while before making the next request
        await Task.Delay(1000); // 1 second
    }



}


What does "it didn't work" mean? Please take some time to read the the Stack Overflow question checklist.
